# IndexOutOfRangeExeption Xamarin Live Player

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, indexoutofboundsexception, xamarin-live-player

I'm studying Xamarin for two weeks now and I'm following the Xamarin.University course (Consuming REST-based Web Services (XAM150)). In an exercise we have to simply check the connection of the phone. My emulator (Android 7.0) in Visual Studio 2017 does it very well. But when I try on my actual phone (Android 7.1) using Xamarin Live Player, the app will not start and the following Error appears on my phone:

> "Visualization Error. Index was outside the bounds of the array.
>   (IndexOutOfRangeExeption)"

I've searched Google and the forum of Xamarin.University but no luck, it seems that no one else has this problem. When I debug, it stops at when it checks the connectivity. I use the Xam.Plugin.Connectivity for asking the connection and yes, it is referenced in all the parts of the project. 
I've come from using this code from the site:

```
using Plugin.Connectivity;

public App() {
   // The root page of your application
   MainPage = CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected 
        ? (Page) new NetworkViewPage() 
        : new NoNetworkPage();
}
```

To this to debug:

```
using Plugin.Connectivity;
public App() {
    InitializeComponent();

    try {
        var isConnected = CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected;

        MainPage = isConnected
                   ? (Page)new NetworkViewPage()
                   : (Page)new NoNetworkPage();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
    //MainPage = new NetworkViewPage();
}
```

All this code works for my emulator, but not for my phone. I can display the different pages on my phone but not when I check for the connectivity so the error is really from the plugin and not from my pages.

Has someone any idea what I can try to make this work?

Comment: Does the code work if you run it without using Live Player? A lot of things are not supported yet and throw odd compile-time errors even if your code is good.

Comment: I'm very new to this and I honestly didn't even now I could do it without the Live player, they always said to do it that way. Have you got a good link on how to implement it on the device without Live Player?

Comment: Just connect your device via a usb cable, it should show up as an option in your device selector. Make sure your device has the developer options enabled and you allow usb debugging, though.

Comment: Thank you! It will indeed have something to do with the live player because with normal implementation on my phone it works fine. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Frauke Nonnenmacher pointed out that it could be **a problem with Xamarin Live Player** and apparantly that is the issue. If I implement it on my phone with USB debugging, it works just fine. It didn't occur to me that Live Player could be the issue since Xamarin.University wants you to use it and I didn't find anybody on the forum there that had the same problem.

My guess is that checking the connection gives a problem with Xamarin Live Player because it works over the network, you can't use the Player if you don't have a wifi connection. So maybe something goes wrong there. 
It is still a mystery why it doesn't work, but a **workaround is just USB debugging**.